# plot values against gaussian curve

Tags: r, statistics, ggplot2

I am new to R and statistics and am still understanding the basic concepts. I need to create a graph of all values in a column of matrix against a Gaussian curve. 
Below is the code

```
#Generates a random matrix with 50 columns
randomMatrix1 <- matrix(c(1:30000), ncol=50)

#Base sequence
x  <- seq(15001,30000, 25)

#Normal function using mean and sd of randomMatrix1
y1 <- dnorm(x/1000,mean=mean(randomMatrix1[,50]),sd=sd(randomMatrix1[,50]))

#Getting the actual values in randomMatrix1
y2 <- cbind(randomMatrix1[,50]/1000)

df <- data.frame(x,y1,y2)


require(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +                    # basic graphical object
geom_line(aes(y=y1), colour="red") +  # first layer
geom_line(aes(y=y2), colour="green")  # second layer
```

I need the output of the two plots on same plot, however the output is not scaled and I tried some combination of varying the mean and sd but nothing worked.

I know this must be a very basic question but which parameter should I change so the two plots get scaled and display right next to each other.

Comment: I'd help but I don know what `meanMat` or `stdDev` is above.

Comment: My bad. That was a typo. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood the question right, but does this help?

```
library(reshape2)
ggplot(melt(df, id="x"), aes(x=x, y=value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scale="free_y")
```

[image]